# Polymorphic object destruction and concurrency

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, parallel-processing, delete-operator

I've got a polymorphic object `o` and two threads `T1` and `T2`.

The destructor of `o`'s most derived class waits for the termination of `T2` before returning.

Is it safe to let `T1` delete `o` while `T2` is calling some virtual functions of `o`? (I mean without using mutual exclusion or any other kind of synchronization mechanisms)

---

I believe it should be safe unless `delete` is allowed to modify `o` (like its pointer to the vtable) even before the completion of the first destructor called. Is this the case?

Comment: I would not do it.  Sounds like running on a high wire without a net to me.  Sounds like an opportunity for intermittent crashes to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you can avoid this, it is fragile and error prone. You can make it work, but small changes in the code can break it.

If the only thing that the block in the complete object destructor does is waiting for the completion of the other thread, and assuming that the base objects have virtual destructors or that the complete object is destroyed directly, *then* it is *safe* to do so. None of the members of the object are destroyed before the body of the destructor completes, and neither are the bases. That means that none of the subobjects that the other thread is using will be destroyed before it completes (and lets the first thread complete the body of the destructor).

That being said, again, try to redesign the code.

Comment: *"None of the members of the object are destroyed before the body of the destructor completes, and neither are the bases"*, What happens if there is a dynamically allocated member(*say a `char *`*) which is deallocated by calling `delete`? The member does get deleted before the body of the destructor completes.If the other thread is accessing this particular member then there is a problem.

Comment: @Als: If you read the answer carefully you will notice that it starts by defining a set of premises as to what the body of that destructor does or does not. The premises as stated as stricter than they need to be, but at any rate calling `delete` on any pointer member falls out of *If the only thing that the block [...] does is waiting*

Comment: ... also, the fact that during later maintenance someone might add code to the destructor that breaks it falls within the description of *small changes in the code can break it.*, *fragile and error prone*

Comment: I added the comment because the detail was not easily evident unless one reads the answer very very carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the scenario where your class has some dynamically allocated members,
`T1`'s destructor may deallocate these members while `T2` is still accessing those members.
This will lead to an Undefined Behavior.

As long as you can ensure that `T1`'s destructor and `T2`'s functions are not operating on the same members you are safe but if you cannot ensure it then you definitely need some synchronization.

Note that the basic logic remains the same, no two threads can read and write simultaneously on the same entity else you end up with race conditions and synchronization issues.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, this is risky, but you can take some steps to reduce the risk. The responsibility for the thread synchronization should be the single responsibility of the most derived class. In particular, this most derived class should NOT have any virtual functions except the destructor.

This design means that T2 cannot be calling any function in the most derived class. At best it can depend on members of the base class of `o`, and those will be valid until the most derived dtor returns - which will be after T2 exits. That means the following sequence is not reordered, except possibly for steps 2 and 3 (harmless)

1. `T2` can access base class methods of `o`
2. In thread `T1`, the dtor of `o` is entered
3. Thread `T2` exits.
4. In thread `T1`, the dtor of `o` returns
5. Base class methods of `o` can no longer be called.